# Plot axis shall start from (0,0,0)

Tags: python, plot, charts, surface

I am trying to plot a 3d surface plot and the axis are not intersecting at (0,0,0), as I intend.
[image: plot]

Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the CSV file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("RanRegCorrAlldat_Miky.csv")

# group the data by var1 and var2 and calculate the mean corr value for each group
grouped = df.groupby(['var1', 'var2'])['corr'].mean()

# extract the x, y, and z values from the grouped data
x = grouped.index.get_level_values('var1')
y = grouped.index.get_level_values('var2')
z = grouped.values

# convert the x and y values to a 2D grid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x), np.unique(y))

# reshape the z values to match the grid
Z = np.reshape(z, (len(np.unique(y)), len(np.unique(x))))

# create a 3D surface plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('var1')
ax.set_ylabel('var2')
ax.set_zlabel('corr')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```